# How to expose Kafka metrics using KafkaIO Beam in python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

Want to be able to expose my consumer and producer metrics in a python written Beam pipeline that uses the KafkaIO library. Examples of the metrics I mean are the ones that you get from the python `confluent-kafka` library -

- bytes-consumed-rate
- fetch-latency-avg
- records-lag
- commit-rate
- consumer lag

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Beam uses Kafka's JVM client, not `confluent-kafka-python`, so you'd need to expose JMX metrics

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Beam's metrics](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.39.0/apache_beam.metrics.metric.html) to publish information as part of your DoFns, but for these metrics it may make more sense to try and query your kafka cluster directly rather than do so from within the pipeline.

Comment: You cannot get client metrics from the kafka cluster directly, such as lag or commit/consume rate

Comment: Where do you get them from?

Comment: The ones listed in the question are available from the consumer client - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-metrics